# Sapepay Form Integration: I am having some problems with a specific account - Error Code : 5080

Tags: php, opayo

**Provider:** Sagepay

**Method:** Form Integration

**Version:** 3.00

**Language:** PHP

**Error docs:** https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes?keyword=5080

I have a library done to do a payment using the form method, but when I change the vendorName and passwordToEncrypt this doesn't work.

I have 2 accounts A and B.

I check both accounts (Sagepay admin) and I don't see a notable difference

I just set the vendor and password

```
 // Work
 $sagePayObj->setVendor('accountA');
 $sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('passA');

 // Doesn't work
 $sagePayObj->setVendor('accountB');
 $sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('passB');
```

I think that the problem is with the vendor or with a config in the Sagepay account.

#### Scenario 1:

```
$sagePayObj->setVendor('accountA');
$sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('passA');
```

**Result:** Good redirect to Sagepay (Show the accountA logo, and the cards)

#### Scenario 2:

```
 $sagePayObj->setVendor('accountA');
 $sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('INCORRECTPASS');
```

**Result:** Redirect to Sagepay with the error 5080 (Show the accountA logo, but doesn't show the cards)

This is good because the vendor is correct but the password no, then Sagepay know the vendor.

#### Scenario 3:

```
$sagePayObj->setVendor('accountB');
$sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('passB');
```

**Result:** Redirect to Sagepay with error 5080 but DOESN'T show the logo and show a different error view like if Sagepay doesn't know the vendor.

#### Scenario 4:

```
$sagePayObj->setVendor('ANITHING');
$sagePayObj->setPasswordToEncrypt('ANITHING');
```

**Result:** I get the same result as scenario 3

This look like Sagepay doesn't know the vendorName, but I have access to the admin using that vendorName. This is so stranger.

Someone has any idea about the reason,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in My Sage Pay under the Invalid tab on the transactions screen. You should get a more informative error message there....